# Having two members of each object bound to a single ListBox

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a `ListBox` that has been bound to an `ObservableCollection` of my custom Tenancy objects, which has properties that include startDate and endDate.

However, I want to have the `ListBox` displaying each `ListBoxItem` of the form:

```
01/01/2001 - 22/12/2012
```

So that's two bound properties and one substring in the middle.

How can I format the output of the `ItemSource` in this way? I understand `DisplayMemberPath` points to the property I want, but I need two `DisplayMemberPaths`, right?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a custom ItemTemplate to achieve this look:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding StartDate}"/><Run Text=" - " /><Run Text="{Binding EndDate}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayMemberPath` is just a shortcut way of saying the `ItemTemplate` should just be a TextBlock with it's Text bound to the DisplayMemberPath item.

If you want your `ItemTemplate` to be more detailed than that, you can overwrite the `ItemTemplate` property.

For example,

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{0:M/d/yy} - {1:M/d/yy}">
                    <Binding Path="StartDate " />
                    <Binding Path="EndDate" />
                 </MultiBinding>
             </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I was not aware of this shortcut going on 'behind the scenes', but it makes sense, thanks.